# Drupal 7: Creating a hierarchical view of nodes of different content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to create a forum like list of nodes. The parent nodes are projects and the child nodes are questions posted related to that project. I have node called post a question, when a user clicks this, it should have a dropdown list of all the project nodes or should be allowed to create a new project and post question under that? I'm new to drupal. How can I go about it?

Comment: A little more explanation of the above question: I would like to create a content type or a node called "Post A Question", which allows users to select the project related to which they want to post a question or a Text field where they could enter the project name and create  a new project if it is not already existing.I also want  a view/node that shows the projects and their related questions in the form of list. What is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

In D6 you can do this with those modules:
-Node Reference URL Widget // for referencing nodes 
-Views attach // for displaying related nodes

here is link to great podcast with instrucitons: http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode37

In D7 "Views attach" is deprecated in favor of its phoenix, EVA.

Answer (score 0):

Views, References, Display Suite, Taxonomy. It's very simple, **try things before asking**.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm quite new to Drupal so dint know which module to try. But, I will keep that in mind. Thanks for your help!

Comment: np, but stackoverflow is not for tutorials it for questions, if you need step-by-step either go to drupalize.me which is the best tutorials drupal site, or ask in drupal.org forums and the great community will guide you :)